# In what ways can you acquire Aquatic Helms?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have noticed that some heart karma vendors sell Aquatic Helms, but I haven't been able to acquire them in any other way. Are there any ways to acquire Aquatic Helms aside from Heart Vendors?

Comment: Asking for a list of all the aquatic helms is way too broad of a question. Limiting the scope of your question to just Aquatic Helms provided by Heart Vendors *may* be limited enough in scope to be acceptable.

Comment: I assumed that Heart Vendors were the only way to obtain Aquatic helms...

Comment: [This site contains a list of all the currently known Aquatic helms in the game.](http://www.gw2db.com/items/armor/aquatichelms). The ones provided by heart vendors will contain a [quote with the vendors name in their description.](http://www.gw2db.com/items/64832-pickinss-medium-rebreather) The list is fairly large, so I still don't think your question is a good fit for the site. The reason is that the question is just too broad to be reasonably answered. I've revised your question to be asking how Aquatic Helms can be acquired, which would cover your secondary question of whether...

Comment: ... it is possible to acquire Aquatic helms through means other than Heart Vendors.

Comment: I think the point of the question is more like "What ways can you gain aquatic helms besides heart vendors"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to craft a [Water Filter](http://www.gw2db.com/recipes/4448-water-filter) with the Armorsmith crafting discipline, but that recipe must be learned from a Karma vendor ([Stout Darkmind](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Stout_Darkmind)) too, and it is only level 20 and only available to heavy armor classes.

They can also be attained randomly by combining other pieces of armor at the [Mystic Forge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_forge).

Rare, level 80 aquatic helms can also drop from defeating [Tequatl the Sunless](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Tequatl_the_Sunless). These were added in the September 17th, 2013 patch, and can be bought on the trading post. These are the most powerful aquatic helms, but are only available in Soldier's stats (Power / Toughness / Vitality).