# How can I craft a new underwater helm?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So far I have made a full set of exotic armour and exotic weapons, but I have one slot yet that I can't work out how to craft - the 'underwater helm' slot.

[image]

I have seen stuff on the trading post for this slot but haven't seen anything in any of the crafting disciplines that I have levelled yet.

How can I craft a new underwater helm? Which crafting discipline do I need to level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83294/in-what-ways-can-you-acquire-aquatic-helms/83361 (and I am really late to notice that)

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Brian's comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently only one craftable breathing apparatus. It is the Water Filter. According to the wiki (thanks to Bazzz for the tip):

> This recipe can be purchased from Stout Darkmind, the renown heart NPC at Blackblade Lake in Diessa Plateau for 126 [karma].

Unfortunately, it's pretty terrible.

The only other option for breathing apparatus replacement, as far as I know, is from a vendor. There are quite a few [heart/karma vendors](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Breathing_apparatus) that offer upgraded breathing apparatuses.

Comment: Perhaps at the time of writing this was true, but now there is a breather that can be crafted, it's not much better than the starting one though: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Recipe:_Water_Filter

Comment: Your best option for this slot currently (assuming you're not happy with a level 20 self-crafted one) is to buy a [Gavbeorn Breather](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gavbeorn_Breather) (from the guy who's got Gavbeorn's Waypoint named after him) for a bit over 1k karma. Or wait and perhaps ANet will make an ascended item available for this slot....

Answer (score 2):

You can now purchase ascended breather recipes from the "Aquabreather Recipes" section of [BUY-4373](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/BUY-4373#vendor34) in the [Mistlock Observatory](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mistlock_Observatory) and [Sanctuary](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mistlock_Sanctuary).

The recipes will appear in the helm section of your crafting discipline (tailor/leather/armour).

They are available in all stat types.